# Can you use the godot engine with a react js web app?

Tags: reactjs, godot, azure-digital-twins

Im looking at building an in browser digital twin application using React JS, and am looking into possible options for rendering a 3D model which the user can freely manipulate and move the camera about.

Could I add in godot as a component to act as a model viewer and then use that to trigger responses and changes in the rest of my UI?

Ive got the react UI set up and ready to go, I basically just need a viewer to add into it

Comment: Yes.  You need to have a `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`, you need to manually attach a `script` to the body and call `init_game()`.  Communication can be done via Godot's Javascript bridge https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_javascriptbridge.html  Keep in mind, last I was aware Godot 4 still didn't have C# support nor Apple ecosystem support for HTML5 exports.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Azure Azure Digital Twins Core client library for [JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/digital-twins-core-readme?view=azure-node-latest)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to integrate Godot Engine into a React JS web application using a digital twin application:

- Create a new React app by running:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
```

- Install a package named `react-godot` using npm for integrating Godot Engine with React applications.

```
npm install --save react-godot
```

- Refer to this for the Godot engine within the [React](https://github.com/d3dc/react-godot).
- Code taken from the [DOC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/visualizing-azure-digital-twins-in-3d/ba-p/2898159).
- Azure Digital Twins Single-page [Application](https://github.com/danhellem/azure-digital-twins-spa-getting-started).

Below is the code for a digital twin application using React JS.
**Code:**

```js
const myComponent = {
  "@id": "dtmi:my_component;1",
  "@type": "Interface",
  "@context": "dtmi:dtdl:context;2",
  displayName: "Component1",
  contents: [
    {
      "@type": "Property",
      name: "ComponentProp1",
      schema: "string"
    }
  ]
};

const createModels = async () => {
  const models = await serviceClient.createModels([myComponent]);
  console.log("Models created:");
  for await (const model of models) {
    console.log(`Model ID: ${model.id}`);
  }
};

// List models
const listModels = async () => {
  const models = await serviceClient.listModels();
  console.log("List of models:");
  for await (const model of models) {
    console.log(`Model ID: ${model.id}`);
  }
};
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

[image]

- For more details, refer to this for Azure Digital Twins 3D Scenes: [Studio](https://github.com/microsoft/iot-cardboard-js).